# Computing absolute distribution from conditioned probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

for a sum $X:= \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{U_n<U_0}$ of a series of random variables $U_1, ..., U_n$, all of them uniformely distributed on the unit interval as is $U_0$, I computed the following conditional probability:

$\mathbb{P}[X=k|U_0] = \binom{n}{k}U_0^k\cdot(1-U_0)^{n-k}$

Now I want to compute the absolute distribution of X, $\mathbb{P}[X=k]$. How do I do it? Please explain!

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: Yeeees. I still don't really know what the difference in the expressions $P(X=k|U_0=u)$ and $P(X=k, U_0=u|U_0)$ is, though.

Comment: Then ask another question.

Comment: I'd rather first think it over twice more or so... then maybe. But thx for consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of the conditional probability one has
$$
P(X=k)={\rm E}[P(X=k\mid U_0)]
$$
or equivalently
$$
P(X=k)=\int_\mathbb{R}P(X=k\mid U_0=u) f_{U_0}(u)\,\mathrm du.
$$

Comment: What is $f_{U_0}$?

Comment: The density of $U_0$.

Comment: Thanks. Now: P(X=k|U0=u) = P(X=k, U0=u| U0)?

Comment: Just replace $U_0$ by $u$ in your expression for $P(X=k\mid U_0)$. The resulting expression is $P(X=k\mid U_0=u)$.